# Setting mesh layer visibility in QGIS application?

Tags: qgis, layers, c++, rendering, mesh

I am utilizing the QgsMeshLayer class to load a NetCDF file that contains multiple variables (temperature, velocity, etc).  I want to be able to set the visible dataset by variable name.  I know how to set layer visibility for entire map layers (C++ here, but PyQGIS is similar), in this example only displaying one layer named "Temperature":

```
QString layerName = "Temperature";
QgsLayerTree *tree = project->instance()->layerTreeRoot(); //project is QgsProject object

for ( QgsMapLayer *layer: qmc->layers() ) // qmc is QgsMapCanvas object
    
    QgsLayerTreeNode *node = tree->findLayer(layer->id());
    
    if ( layer->name() == layerName )
    {
       node->setItemVisibilityChecked(true);

    } else
    {
       node->setItemVisibilityChecked(false);
    }

}
```

There isn't much documentation/examples out there on mesh layers as there are for rasters or vectors, but I've pieced together what I could from the API docs.  I can access group tree items similar to above as follows:

```
QgsMeshLayer *mesh = new QgsMeshLayer("/path/to/file.nc","MyData","mdal");
QString dataName = "Temperature";

for ( int &i: mesh->datasetGroupsIndexes() )
{
   QgsMeshDatasetIndex did = i;
   QgsMeshDatasetGroupTreeItem *child = tree->childFromDatasetGroupIndex(i);
   
   if ( child->name() == dataName )
   {
      child->setIsEnabled(true);

   } else
   {
      child->setIsEnabled(false);
   }
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work.  I can also access the member function "setSublayerVisibility" using the mesh layer's data provider, but haven't had luck here either.  My next option that I haven't tried yet is to look into the mesh layer rendering where I can set "hidden" layers to all transparent but am hoping there is a better way to do this.

Comment: If you also seek a PyQGIS solution then please ask about that ins separate question that includes a PyQGIS code attempt.